# Como programar de acordo com boas praticas de design OO?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software

eu fiz este programa, simples e nada de complicado.
O meu problema é que isto embora esteja a fazer exatamente o que quero, isto não segue padrões corretos de design orientado a objetos.
O que devo fazer para, por exemplo, acabar com variaveis estaticas, extends, gets e sets...?

Este é o código que tenho.

```
package com.mycompany.exerciciocontadores;

public abstract class Contador {

private String cliente;
private String id;
private double consumo;

private static String CLIENTE_POR_OMISSAO = "sem cliente";
private static String ID_POR_OMISSAO = "sem ID";
private static double CONSUMO_POR_OMISSAO = 0;

public Contador(String cliente, String id, double consumo) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
    this.id = id;
    this.consumo = consumo;
}

public Contador() {
    cliente = CLIENTE_POR_OMISSAO;
    id = ID_POR_OMISSAO;
    consumo = CONSUMO_POR_OMISSAO;
}

public String getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public double getConsumo() {
    return consumo;
}

public void setCliente(String cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setConsumo(double consumo) {
    this.consumo = consumo;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Contador{" + "cliente=" + cliente + ", id=" + id + ", consumo=" + consumo + '}';
}

public abstract double calcularCusto();

}
```

A subclasse:

```
package com.mycompany.exerciciocontadores;

public class ContadorGas extends Contador {

private static final String PREFIXO = "GAS-";
private static int contador = 0;
private double custoUnitario = 0.8;

public ContadorGas(String cliente, double consumo) {
    super(cliente, PREFIXO + (++contador), consumo);
}

public static int getContador() {
    return contador;
}

public double getCustoUnitario() {
    return custoUnitario;
}

public static void setContador(int contador) {
    ContadorGas.contador = contador;
}

public void setCustoUnitario(double custoUnitario) {
    this.custoUnitario = custoUnitario;
}

@Override
public double calcularCusto() {
    return getConsumo() * custoUnitario;
}

}
```

Comment: E qual o problema em se usar variaveis estaticas, usar herança, getters e settter? Se o recurso existe na linguagem, é porque ele pode ser usado, o que não pode é usar sem saber o que está fazendo.

Comment: @Articuno problema nenhum. se é um recurrso da língua, deve ser utilizado
mas não segue padrões correto de design orientado a objetos.
por exemplo, os gets e sets em muitos casos sao desnecessarios
o extends pode seriamente afetar a facilidade de manutenção do código

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orienta%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-objetos?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: Onde você leu que não segue os padrões corretos? Pode mostrar? Nunca ouvi falar nada a respeito disso.

Comment: http://www.oodesign.com/
Aqui por exemplo
ou aqui http://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code/

Comment: Não faz muito sentido dizer que `get`s e `set`s não são boa prática de OO, já que sem eles todas as variáveis seriam públicas, sem encapsulamento, isso sim poderia ser uma má pratica

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam A questão do get e set é o uso incorreto deles. Muitos desenvolvedores costumam criar métodos get/set para todos os atributos da classe que é o mesmo que deixar os atributos públicos só que utilizando um caminho mais longo.

Comment: @skidils Acho que você levou os princípios ao extremo. Variáveis estáticas, herança e gets/sets não são uma má prática. O que os princípios do SOLID diz é que você deve ponderar quando utilizá-los. Simplesmente removê-los do seu código não vai deixar o seu código com um design melhor. Você tem que entender porque e em quais situações essas abordagens não são interessantes.

Comment: Dicas: é interessante você notar que está retornando `String` para `getCliente()` ao invés de retornar um Objeto `Cliente`; você também está usando `double` para calcular dinheiro ao invés de `BigDecimal`, e, não tenho certeza, mas parece que está usando Strings nesse código _Model_ que vão parar na GUI. Coloque também código de validação para garantir que os valores setados serão íntegros, como @Rogi93 disse. Por fim, reveja o Encapsulamento (procure não deixar um código externo usar o Contador como "fantoche", deixe o próprio Contador cuidar de sua lógica, funcionamento e integridade).

Answer (score 3):

A parte básica você já fez. Você pode pensar se deve usar get e set em todos os atributos porque tem coisa que a classe não deveria mudar. Você pode perguntar porque alterar o id do contador, se não pode mudar, não pode ter um set.

Outra coisa que pode mudar e ter um método que aumente e talvez algum que diminua o contador. Será que pode deixar mexer no contador de qualquer jeito? Pode zerar, pode colocar um numero alto? E pode ter uma validação como o amigo acima escreveu.

Pode ser que queira fazer o consumo ser protected aí não precisaria chamar getConsumo.

Ah lembrei que o custoUnitario deveria ser static também.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez nao seja exatamente o que procura, mas uma boa pratica e utilizar o metodo set para controlar as consistências dos dados e evitar que valores negativos sejam salvos onde nao devem.

Ao inves disso:

```
public void setConsumo(double consumo) 
{
    this.consumo = consumo;
}
```

Isso:

```
public void setConsumo(double consumoCliente )

     {
         if(consumoCliente >= 0.0)
            consumo = consumoCliente;
         else
           consumo = 0.0;
    }
```

E sobre  a utilizacao de herança em seu codigo, sinceramente nao vejo nada fora de regra, alias é uma excelente pratica. Uma alternativa a herança seria a composição, porem havera repeticao de codigo que nao uma boa pratica.